# Blender alternative to MAYA viewFit()

Tags: rendering, camera

I have following code in Maya. How can I implement this in Blender ?

```
# Frame object to the camera. You should not use it if you want fixed position of the camera    
def frameObjectToCamera(camera_name, object):
    cmds.viewFit(camera_name)
    return
```

According to official docs, this is what **viewFit** does :

> The viewFit command positions the specified camera so its point-of-view contains all selected objects other than itself. If no objects are selected, everything is fit to the view (excepting cameras, lights, and sketching plannes). The fit-factor, if specified, determines how much of the view should be filled. If a camera is not specified, the camera in the active view will be used. After the camera is moved, its center of interest is set to the center of the bounding box of the objects.

Comment: What it does in Maya? Fit the view to the selected object? If so, that's already part of Blender. In the 3d viewport go to *View > Frame Selected*. Enable developer extras to get the operator command.

Comment: Period key on the Numpad. - Forward Slash shows just the selected object in isolation.

Comment: @brockmann
I guess it fits the selected object to the view of the Camera. So the Camera will be positioned such that the selected object is in its point-of-view.